# JTable .getColumnName not updating after .setHeaderValue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jtableheader

I'm pretty new with Java and have a basic question. I've been trying to find an answer on the internet but I still don't understand how I can retrieve the new column names once I have changed them.

I'm using Netbeans and have the following code:

```
int columnNum = 2

jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColum(columnNum).setHeaderValue("Test");
repaint();

System.out.println(jTable1.getColumnName(columnNum));
```

My result will not be printed as Test but I will have the old value that was previously there. I understand I should use something maybe called `fireTableStrucutreChanged()` but I'm not sure how to do that in Netbeans. If that is the idea could you please explain to me what to do.

Many thanks and sorry for the trouble this may cause you all.

**EDIT**

Here is an example. The form is updating so that is fine but the internal value (when fetching the name of the column doesn't update):

*Form - Image*

http://s13.postimg.org/t8xiadfl3/test.jpg

*Code*

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String remove = "Title 1";
    for(int x = 0; x < jTable1.getColumnCount(); x++) {
        if(jTable1.getColumnName(x).equals(remove)) {
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setHeaderValue("Test");
            repaint();
            System.out.println(jTable1.getColumnName(x));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT - Added creation code for the form.**

```
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(153, 153, 153)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(174, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 139, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}
```

Comment: use JXTable - its JXTableHeader listens to changes of column properties

Comment: thanks @kleopatra but I would prefer to stick with jTable if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It might not be pretty but basically I used a ArrayList to create a virtual table in the program. When I would change one of the columns I would replace the value of the Array with the new value. When fetching the new value I would then go at find it in the Array.

I'm sure there is a better way but it solved my problem.

Many thanks all of you for your help.

Comment: sounds fishy .. even though it _appears_ to solve your problem, most probably it doesn't: you didn't find the _real_ reason of the problem (not even, whether it's in your code or in your expectation) so you couldn't possibly fix the real problem ;-) Whatever you see is pure coincidence ...

Answer (score -1):

After change headerValue, you need to repaint `JTableHeader`:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Test");
table.getTableHeader().repaint();
```

EDIT: change `actionPerformed()` like next:

```
String remove = "Title 1";
for(int x = 0; x < t.getColumnCount(); x++) {
  if(jTable1.getColumnName(x).equals(remove)) {
  jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setHeaderValue("Test");
  jTable1t.getTableHeader().repaint();
  System.out.println(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).getHeaderValue());
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry that doesn't work. Try adding System.out.println(jTable1.getColumnName(0)); You will notice you still get the previous table.

Comment: you don't need the repaint(), but everything depends of underlaying model ..., question isn't answerable without an SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: Thanks @mKorbel. I've added an image and provided some code which I hope can help you.

Comment: @Michael shows your `TableModel` implementation and creation of `JTable` without that it's answerable.

Comment: @mKorbel you are right, but I prefere use repaint() for avoiding artefacts.

Comment: Hi @alex2410, I've added all the code which creates the jTable and form.